Phases in equilibrium and not in equilibrium
What is the difference between the phases of a substance in equilibrium or not in equilibrium? For example, at room temperature, water is a liquid. It is also a vapor above the liquid formed from the surface of the liquid, and the vapor exerts a pressure (vapor pressure) on the liquid. Why are the phase change lines called equilibrium lines if the water vapor is in equilibrium with the water below boiling point? At the boiling point of water, any heat added to the system allows vapor in the body of the liquid to push outward and form bubbles. The temperature of the liquid will not change until all of the liquid has become a gas (the vapor can become hotter). At this point, it is said that the water is in equilibrium with the vapor of water only if there is no more heat added to the system.
Is it because the pressure of the vapor below boiling point is less than the ambient pressure exerted on the liquid? That would mean the vapor and the gas are not in equilibrium with each other.
From a physics viewpoint, if phases are not in equilibrium with each other outside of the point of phase change, then the transition from a liquid to a gas at the boiling point is reversible but below or above the boiling point it is not. Where do we lose heat that we cannot convert to work in the process of an irreversible phase change from a liquid to a gas below or above boiling point? If we lose heat as so, then the entropy of the universe is not the same after some water vapor forms and recondenses on the surface of the liquid at below boiling point.
On a phase diagram, we have lines dividing the phases at the boiling/melting points, freezing/condensation points, and sublimation/deposition points. What does it mean for a substance to be at equilibrium when it is on these lines? Is it not possible for water vapor to also be at equilibrium at room temperature.
Poutnik's answer is best "The line has two meanings. 1/It gives for closed systems the equilibrium vapor p for given T and vice versa. 2) It gives the boiling point for given external pressure for open systems." Phases in equilibrium and not in equilibrium
My understanding now is "At a given temperature, the system will tend to equilibrium where the water vapor is at the vapor pressure p on the liquid/gas line. It will boil when the vapor pressure is equal to the applied pressure. I assume in a closed system at constant volume, the applied pressure is the pressure of the other gases. 'As the temperature of a liquid increases, the vapor pressure of the liquid increases until it equals the external pressure, or the atmospheric pressure in the case of an open container.'[1]" Phases in equilibrium and not in equilibrium
reference for my comment:
[1]https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_Principles_of_Modern_Chemistry_(Oxtoby_et_al.)/Unit_3%3A_The_States_of_Matter/10%3A_Solids_Liquids_and_Phase_Transitions/10.4%3A_Phase_Equilibrium

At the boiling point of water .....  it is said that the water is in equilibrium with the vapor of water. Boiling is not an equilibrium state. It can be a steady state, what is not an (thermodynamic) equilibrium. An equilibrium is when there is zero net phase transition, because chemical potentials ( $\mu_i = \dfrac{\text{d}G_i}{\text{d}n}$ ) of phases are equal.

is this what you mean? "You can have a liquid/solid system at equilibrium at the melting temperature, but in this case no net melting occurs. You can have a liquid/vapor system at equilibrium at the boiling temperature, but in this case no net evaporation or boiling occurs." https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/122929/melting-and-boiling-really-equilibrium#:~:text=Just%20for%20clarity%2C%20let%20me%20emphasize%20that%2C%20as,it%20can%20be%20at%20equilibrium%20at%20any%20ratio%29.

Yes,it is. An ongoing process and an equilibrium state are mutually excluding.

could you explain why the phase change lines are called equilibrium lines even through the water vapor evaporating from the surface of the water can exist in equilibrium with the water in a closed container, exerting a constant vapor pressure at a given temperature below the boiling point?

The line has two meanings. 1/It gives for closed systems the equilibrium vapor p for given T and vice versa. 2) It gives the boiling point for given external pressure for open systems.

Thank you. That answers my question very well. In a closed system, on the phase diagram we can find the equilibrium vapor pressure p at the phase change line.  How do we know if the liquid will boil? is it when p is equal to the partial pressure of all the other gases in the system combined in contact with the surface of the water?

You may find useful and more suited for systematic study if you  review the search results for site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org phase diagram liquid vapor equilibrium evaporation boiling

Great! I am starting to understand this more. At a given temperature, the system will tend to equilibrium where the water vapor is at the vapor pressure p on the liquid/gas line. It will boil when the vapor pressure is equal to the applied pressure. I assume in a closed system at constant volume, the applied pressure is the pressure of the other gases.
"As the temperature of a liquid increases, the vapor pressure of the liquid increases until it equals the external pressure, or the atmospheric pressure in the case of an open container." (reference in the question)

You seem to be asking multiple questions:

What is the difference between the phases of a substance in equilibrium or not in equilibrium?
Why is the vapor of water only at equilibrium with the liquid of the water at boiling point, and not at room temperature?


The answer to 1. is that not all molecules of a substance have the same energy. If one were able to look at each molecule of water in a beaker filled with rapidly boiling water, those in the vapor bubbles have higher energy than those in the liquid. In addition to the latent heat of vaporization, the steam in a bubble can be hotter than the 100°C liquid temperature, at atmospheric pressure, as in this demonstration.

And number 2. is a misstatement. Water in an undisturbed sealed container, at any temperature, eventually reaches equilibrium with the vapor. Yes, some vapor condenses, and some liquid evaporates, but, because the rates are equal,  i.e, $\ce{liquid ⇄ vapor}$, the water is in equilibrium with the vapor.



Thank you. For question 1, are the properties of water vapor below boiling point different from above boiling point? Water vapor exists below boiling point, and boiling just happens to be a point when water vapor can exist as bubbles in a liquid. For question 2, Why are the phase separation lines called equilibrium lines? As you said, is the water vapor not always in equilibrium with the liquid even outside of the phase separation lines?

A phase diagram describes the physical states of a PURE substance [or a defined mixture, this is advanced phase diagram, save it for later] as a function of vapor pressure and temperature. Every point in the diagram defines a T and P [vapor pressure when vapor is present] and where the point is tells what phases are present. When 2 or 3 phases are present each point describes an equilibrium situation.  When vapor is present the pressure in a phase diagram is the Vapor Pressure. When vapor is absent the pressure is mechanical, not an inert gas such as air.
The diagram is expressed by the Gibbs Phase Rule: Degrees of freedom, F, equals Components, C, minus the number of phases, P, plus 2. F = C - P + 2. Degrees of freedom are generally pressure [again P] Temperature [T] and mole fraction or activity of the chemical species. Components are the sum of the species present less the relationships among them. This last bit can get complicated, so I recommend reading about it.
For a one substance system with 3 common phases: gas, liquid, solid the relationships are straightforward.  When one phase is present there is no relationship so C =1; when 2 phases represent there is one relationship so there are 2 species and one relationship so 2-1 again means one component. Finally when 3 phases are present there are two relationships to define the situation: the equal vapor pressure of the solid and liquid; so 3-2 again means one component. A final note about the +2 in the equation, this refers to temperature and pressure. Should other fields such as electric, magnetic, radiation, gravitational, etc., be involved this number is increased accordingly.
When one phase is present, a space in the phase diagram, F = 1-1+2 = 2; there are two degrees of freedom. This means that both T and P must be determined to define a specific state. When two phases are present F = 1-2+2 = 1. This means that if either T or P is determined the other has a definite value. This mathematically refers to a line. A line in a phase diagram is the locus of all points when the two phases are in equilibrium. It is NOT a line separating the two phases. When three phases are present F = 1-3+2 = 0.  This means that a measured value of one freedom automatically describes the other two. This is an intersection of three lines in the phase diagram a point or singularity.
The equilibrium lines are curved. The solid-liquid, liquid-gas, solid-gas, lines do not really meet at a point they meet at a cusp that is glimpse into a fourth dimension involving the energies of fusion and evaporation and the compressibilities of the liquid and solids.  This fourth dimension realizes when an inert gas, a second component, is introduced.
Boiling is an additional process. Evaporation into an inert atmosphere is essentially evaporation into a vacuum; the liquid molecules move into the empty space between the gas molecules As the temperature increases [or pressure decreases] the only molecules in contact with the liquid slowly become the liquid molecules; this means the pressure on the liquid becomes the vapor pressure. If the inert atmosphere is unconstrained [open atmosphere, vacuum pump etc.], additional heat increases evaporation of the liquid and the added vapor pushes back the atmosphere doing work and maintaining a constant pressure. Back to the phase rule if P is defined T becomes also defined; as long as the vapor can expand by pushing back the atmosphere P and T remain constant. This differs from a constant volume, here increasing energy raises both T and P to new points along the line. This is the difference between Cv and Cp and internal energy, U, and enthalpy H = U+PV.
Are there differences between water molecules. The properties do differ with actual physical states. There are kinetic and thermodynamic differences with particle size etc. This is observed in nano and exochemistry where small particles react differently. Small crystals have higher solubilities and vapor pressures than large, small droplets have a higher vapor pressure. It comes down to whether the property is a function of the average energies of the material or the energy of an almost individual molecule in a drop or crystal. Another topic.

Excellent. Thank you. What do you mean by "Evaporation into an inert atmosphere is essentially evaporation into a vacuum; the liquid molecules move into the empty space between the gas molecules." Is this that the vapor pressure we consider on the surface is the partial pressure of the liquid that is evaporating?

I am looking forward to reading more about Gibbs Phase Rule. I do not understand this entirely "When vapor is absent the pressure is mechanical, not an inert gas such as air". Is there not always a vapor unless the liquid is in a closed container and completely fills the volume?

When solid and liquid are only present there is no head space and no vapor the pressure is mechanical, the container. Were there headspace as in the freezing point of water in the open air there is a new triple point; both condensed phases are in equilibrium with vapor; the inert gas is a second component. For the first comment evaporating into a vacuum or the space between molecules does no work so adding heat raises the liquid T and vapor pressure. When the vapor is constrained by a constant P it does work and P is constant this restricts the system to one point on the liquid -vapor line.
